# copy 2d image data with this function - why it works?

Tags: c, image

The following code copies 2d data from src to dst without "issues" apparently in the test shown below, but I knew the code is wrong and the correct code is also provided. Here, I'm asking about what is exactly wrong. **My explanation is that the pointer itself is a multi-byte variable, and dereferencing a double pointer is in trouble if the size of pointed value (unsigned char) is different from the size of the pointer.** What do you think?

I have to point out that the cast "unsigned char **" doesn't change the underlying data, so if the code is modified to use another local indirection, everything actually works perfect, see below:

```
void copy_2d_data(unsigned char **dst, unsigned char **src, int w, int h)
{
    printf("copy_2d_data img width = %d, height = %d\n  ......\n", w, h);
    // wrong code:
    for (int row=0; row<w-2; row++) {     //note here -> w-2
        for (int col=0; col<h-2; col++) { //note here -> h-2
            //**dst++ = **src++; //this will cause seg fault, so don't try it
            *dst++ = *src++;
        }
    }
 #if 0 // the correct code starts:
    unsigned char *s = (unsigned char *)src;
    unsigned char *d = (unsigned char *)dst;
    for (int row=0; row<w; row++) {
        for (int col=0; col<h; col++) {
            *d++ = *s++;
        }
    }
 #endif
    printf("copy_2d_data done\n");
}
```

Test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    unsigned char s_img[][5] = {{1,  2,  3,  4,  5 },
                                {6,  7,  8,  9,  10},
                                {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                                {16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
                                {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}
                               };

    unsigned char d_img[][5] = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
                               };
    int w = 5, h = 5;

    //display what is in img buf:
    unsigned char *s = (unsigned char *)s_img;
    unsigned char *d = (unsigned char *)d_img;
    printf("\ns_img:\n");
    for (int row =0; row<w; row++) { 
        for (int col =0; col<h; col++) {
            printf("%u,", *s++);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\nd_img:\n");
    for (int row =0; row<w; row++) { 
        for (int col =0; col<h; col++) {
            printf("%u,", *d++);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    //copy:
    copy_2d_data( (unsigned char **)d_img, (unsigned char **)s_img, w, h );

    printf("\nnow check result\nd_img:\n");
    d = (unsigned char *)d_img;
    for (int row=0; row<w; row++) {
        for (int col =0; col<h; col++) {
            printf("%u,", *d++);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
s_img:
1,2,3,4,5,
6,7,8,9,10,
11,12,13,14,15,
16,17,18,19,20,
21,22,23,24,25,

d_img:
0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,

copy_2d_data img width = 5, height = 5
  ......
copy_2d_data done

now check result
d_img:
1,2,3,4,5,
6,7,8,9,10,
11,12,13,14,15,
16,17,18,19,20,
21,22,23,24,25,
```

Comment: The code looks like C code. Do you really use a C++ compiler?

Comment: How are `s_img` and `d_img` defined and initialised?

Comment: It "works" because of **undefined behaviour** and "things". There is nothing remotely **correct** in this program though. It is like asking "I ate mud but I am still feeling fine, why is that?"

Comment: the question and answers appear to be c, so i removed the other tag

Comment: "The following code copies 2d data from src to dst without issues". No, this is not quite what happens here. Here's another description: "by randomly adding casts and manipulating loop bounds, I have coerced a single test into passing on my machine". Does this sound more realistic to you?

Comment: The above comments didn’t really have a clue. The key is the starting address and data size. All those casts don’t matter, they just fool the compiler.

Comment: You have changed the code since you've got the answers and the above comments. This invalidates the answers. Don't do that. If you want an answer about modified code, ask a new question.

Comment: @n.m. , No. Your assumption is incorrect. I had the modified code years before this post was out. However, that piece of modified code is neither my interest nor the key issue to discuss here. The intention of this post was to share and pinpoint the real problem in the problematic code.

Comment: That's a nice theory but so far it is not supported by facts. The facts are, there is a history of editing on SO accessible to everyone, with timestamps. So everyone can see what was edited to what and when.

Comment: @n.m. Hey, did you read: “My explanation is that the pointer itself is a multi-byte variable, and dereferencing a double pointer is in trouble if the size of pointed value (unsigned char) is different from the size of the pointer.”? That is before the editing, plus that the editing just doesn’t change my initial point, and it doesn’t help you at all!

Comment: Your code before editing was totally wrong and would not pass any tests. Your claim that it worked "without issues" doesn't hold water. If you have a question about your code after editing, please ask a new question. I'm not going to comment on this question further. Thank you for your time and have a nice day.

Comment: You did not read the whole thing before jumping to your conclusion

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work, or it seems to work (for now) by bad luck.

Pointer-to-pointers don't have anything to do with 2D arrays nor can they point at a 2D array. You can use pointer-to-pointer when dealing with *an array of pointers*, but that's not the case here. That's the reason why you can't compile this code without adding the incorrect casts during the `copy_2d_data` call.

You could change the function to this:

```
void copy_2d_data (int row, int col, unsigned char dst[row][col], unsigned char src[row][col])
{
    printf("copy_2d_data img width = %d, height = %d\n  ......\n", w, h);

    for (int r=0; r<row-2; r++) {
        for (int c=0; c<col-2; c++) {
          dst[row][col]
        }
    }
    printf("copy_2d_data done\n");
}
```

(Also please don't call things height + width one moment, then row + col the next moment, that's the road to madness.)

Then call the function as:

```
copy_2d_data(w, h, d_img, s_img);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be suspicious of this code, because it's rather amusingly wrong.

If you want to copy a two-dimensional array of `char`, you have `w` × `h` bytes to copy.  A function that accepted two `char *` pointers, or two `void *` pointers, would work.  (Example below, for completeness.)  Significantly, a simple call to `memcpy` would work equally well, since copying contiguous bytes is precisely what `memcpy` does.

But this `copy_2d_data` function doesn't copy bytes.  It copies `void *` pointers.  Depending on the machine you're using, a `void *` pointer is probably either 32 or 64 bits, or stated another way, either 4 or 8 bytes.  So where this function should be copying 1 byte at a time, it's actually copying 4 or 8 bytes at a time.  So I would expect it to rather badly overflow the destination array.

But!  Its loop does not run `w` × `h` times.  For some unexplained reason, it runs (`w` - 2) × (`h` - 2) times.  Sometimes, at least, those two near-random subtractions will arrange that the function not over-copy too much.  (And sometimes they'll mean that the function doesn't copy enough.  Once in a while, they might even happen to achieve just the right amount of copying.)

It looks like someone wrongly assumed that a two-dimensional array involved two-level pointers.  (That's false, but it's a common and rather obvious mistake.)  When the function didn't work, someone might have discovered that it was copying too much, and thought of some imaginary reason why subtracting 2 from the dimensions was a sensible fix.  (Obviously it's not.)

This would work:

```
void copy_2d_data(unsigned char *dst, unsigned char *src, int w, int h)
{
    for (int row=0; row<w; row++) {
        for (int col=0; col<h; col++) {
            *dst++ = *src++;
        }
    }
}
```

So would this:

```
void copy_2d_data(unsigned char *dst, unsigned char *src, int w, int h)
{
    for (int i=0; i<w*h; i++) {
        *dst++ = *src++;
    }
}
```

You could also write it like this:

```
void copy_byte_array(unsigned char *dst, unsigned char *src, int n)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        *dst++ = *src++;
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
copy_byte_array( (unsigned char *)d_img, (unsigned char *)s_img, w * h );
```

And once you've done that, it's equivalent to `memcpy`, which you could call instead:

```
memcpy( d_img, s_img, w * h );
```

---

For your 5×5 example, you wanted to copy 25 bytes, and instead you're copying either 3×3×4 = 36 bytes or 3×3×8 = 72 bytes.  Still significantly too much.  I'm surprised it worked, but I tried it on my machine, where I was even more surprised that it  worked!  (I know my machine has 64-bit pointers, and 72 is obviously *significantly* more than 25!)

To convince yourself of what's going on, here are two things you can try.

1. After the call to `copy_2d_data`, try printing out both the source and destination arrays.  You might find (I did find) that the source array had been altered, doubtless because of the overcopying.
2. Swap the declarations of `s_img` and `d_img`: declare `d_img` first, then `s_img`.  You may find (I did find) that the program crashes, because something more important gets overwritten by the over-copying.

And, in the end, you'll obviously want to re-think the way you're copying your image arrays.

Comment: If you need to cast the pointers during function call, you have a bug somewhere. Also, "manged arrays" is pretty obsolete, pre-C99 style.